# Activating/Deactivating Constraints on orientationchange

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I don't get it to work and I don't know why... the other questions + answers sadly didn't help.

Tested devices:
iPhone 6
iPad 2

Relevant code:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
    updateConstraints()
}
override func viewWillLayoutSubview() {
    updateConstraints()
}

func updateConstraints() {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(layoutLandscape!)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(layoutPortrait!)
    }
    else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(layoutPortrait!)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(layoutLandscape!)
    }
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

layoutLandscape and layoutPortrait being arrays of constraints.

Cases this does work:
- iPad loading the view, portrait and landscape
- iPad rotating the view, portrait and landscape
- iPhone loading the view, portrait and landscape
- iPhone rotating the view, only landscape -> portrait

does not work:
- iPhone portrait -> landscape

The iPhone rotation works this way when I activate the portrait as default in the storyboard. If I change that to the landscape constraints, then portrait -> landscape works and the other one doesn't.

The error message (which is also not really helping...) is just that I break some constraints (which are quite a few, so too hard to narrow it down), but then I wonder why it does work when I load the view in both orientations on iPhone.
And why does it work completely on the iPad? It's not like that thing has a much higher resolution than the iPhone or anything like that.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

When you activate layout constraints, they are immediately checked if they are in conflict with other constraints. If so, some are broken, i.e. removed.

In your code, this can happen because you first activate the constraints, at which point you have too many, conflicting constraints.

So the first approach is to first deactivate the no longer relevant ones and then activate the new ones (instead of the other way round).

Another and supposedly more efficient approach is to not activate and deactivate the constraints, but to set the priority to 999 for the currently relevant ones and to 1 for the irrelevant ones. (Note: It's 999 and not 1000.)

Comment: Tried both ways, activating first and deactivating first, both the same... I will try that with priority, good idea... PS wouldn't it suffice to set all to 999? Activating one set should do nothing then because they are all optional and when I deactivate the other set... will try that in a bit, no time atm :/

Comment: @Inuyaki It's somewhat surprising that it doesn't work. When exactly does the error message (*Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints*) occur? At startup or when your rotate the device? After which Swift statement exactly?

Comment: As written in the post only when rotating and only on iPhone and only in one direction... i did set everything to 999, no error anymore, but other things happen. I guess I can fix it out from here on, maybe just set both sets to 999 before the activating/deactivating and then to 1000 back or so... I'll see :)

Comment: @Inuyaki Ok. But once you set the priority to 1000, you can no longer change it. That's how it works.